# Mailchimp API limit in post request

Tags: node.js, rest, mailchimp

I am working with the mailchimp api. I am running into a problem where i exceed their limit of 10.
In the get request you can solve this with pagination and offset. But how can you solve this in a post request, it's not like you can have pagination in post requests..

This is how my code is running :

```
allEmails.forEach(email => {
    const emailHash = md5(email); 
    if(mailChimpMails.indexOf(email) === -1) {
        mailChimpPost('POST',`lists/4d2d65c130/members` , JSON.stringify({"email_address" : email , "status": "subscribed"})).then( res => {
            console.log(res);
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err); 
        });
    }else{
         mailChimpPost('PATCH',`lists/4d2d65c130/members/${emailHash}` ,  JSON.stringify({"status": "subscribed"})).then(res => {
             console.log(res)
         }).catch(err => {
             console.log(err); 
         });
    }
})
```

All emails is an array of emails which i loop through and add them individually to my audience in mailchimp. It adds a few but after a while of running it throws an error of 429 :

> statusCodeError: 429 -
> "{"type":"http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/","title":"Too
> Many Requests","status":429,"detail":"You have exceeded the
> limit of 10 simultaneous
> connections.","instance":"myinstance"}"

Comment: Found the issue i think. Maybe i need to await one request before doing the other.. 
so instead of a foreach loop i used a for of loop with await

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little late, but better late than never and maybe you've discovered this in the meantime, yourself.

### Use the batch endpoint

https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/api/lists/batch-subscribe-or-unsubscribe

Here's an example of CURL code that should get you on your way:

```
curl -X POST \
  'https://${dc}.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/{list_id}?skip_merge_validation=<SOME_BOOLEAN_VALUE>&skip_duplicate_check=<SOME_BOOLEAN_VALUE>' \
  --user "anystring:${apikey}"' \
  -d '{"members":[],"update_existing":false}'
```

Where `members` is an array of objects, with at least one property `email_address`.

The batch job is passed off to Mailchimp relatively quickly freeing up both your app and your connections to MailChimp.